# Point VSCode to a TSConfig independant of the repo

Tags: typescript, eslint, visual-studio-code

I want to point VSCode to a TSConfig independent of whatever repo I am in for syntax highlighting.

Within my company, we are working towards utilizing more strict typescript. However, we aren't to the point that leadership feels comfortable enabling Strict mode for the whole repo. I want to point VSCode and/or ESLint to my own TSConfig file, independent of my companies repo, without actually needing to modify my companies repo (currently, I have a version of TSConfig I paste in and then revert for each PR).

I have googled and searched here for an answer but have come up short so far.